# Access violation in c++

Tags: c++

Beginner programmer here. I'm getting an access violation error in my directed graph program, and I'm wondering if anyone can tell me why.

Here's the trouble code (don't worry, it's not much). This code is from my main function. I've just read some info in from a file, parsed it, and am trying to insert it into a bucket using a function called InitialInsert.

```
//Store parsed file values
sourceCity = line[0]; 
destinationCity = line[1]; 
miles = stoi(line[2]); 
cost = stoi(line[3]); 

//Insert parsed values into Info bucket
graph.InitialInsert(sourceCity, destinationCity, miles, cost, size++); //Size is initialized to 0
```

This is the initial insert function.

```
//InitialInsert function
void Graph::InitialInsert(string source, string destination, int distance, int price, int index)
{
    InfoBuckets[index]->sourceCity = source; 
    InfoBuckets[index]->destinationCity = destination; 
    InfoBuckets[index]->miles = distance; 
    InfoBuckets[index]->cost = price; 
}
```

And this is from my header file.

```
static int const ARRAY_SIZE = 1000; 
struct InitialInfo
{
    string sourceCity; 
    string destinationCity;
    int miles; 
    int cost; 
};
InitialInfo* InfoBuckets[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

I'm getting the error "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCE4" when I hit the first line of my InitialInsert function. This is probably a silly problem, but can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't make the pointers in `InfoBuckets` point anywhere good before using them.

Comment: Where is `size` initialized? What value should it be when you first call the function?

Comment: it looks like you're not allocating any space for your individual `InitialInfo` objects

Comment: Why are you using an array of pointers? Why not just an array of `InitialInfo`?

Comment: For that matter, why are you using a C-style array, instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: I think that you have to allocate each individual `InitialInfo` object with the [new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).  I believe that [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/?kw=malloc) will probably also work, but people are going to get on my case if I don't mention that `malloc` is a `c` thing, and it's probably not a good idea to use it in `c++`

Comment: @SamIam _"I believe that malloc will probably also work"_ o-O ...

Comment: @SamIam "it's absolutely a terrible idea to use it in c++". Fixed that for you...

Answer (score 1):

You are defined an ARRAY of 1000 pointers of InifitalInfo, but InitialInfo[0] never has been initialized.

Try this:

**Array of Objects**

```
InitialInfo InfoBuckets[ARRAY_SIZE];

...

void Graph::InitialInsert(string source, string destination, int distance, int price, int index)
{
   InfoBuckets[index].sourceCity = source; 
   InfoBuckets[index].destinationCity = destination; 
   InfoBuckets[index].miles = distance; 
   InfoBuckets[index].cost = price; 
}
```

or

**Array of pointers**

```
InitialInfo *InfoBuckets[ARRAY_SIZE];

...

InfoBuckets[0] = new InitialInfo(); // You need create the object first before using

...

void Graph::InitialInsert(string source, string destination, int distance, int price, int index)
{
   InfoBuckets[index]->sourceCity = source; 
   InfoBuckets[index]->destinationCity = destination; 
   InfoBuckets[index]->miles = distance; 
   InfoBuckets[index]->cost = price; 
}
```

As @Roddy recomends, you must use smart pointers instead of new operators. You can read about in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) .

Comment: what if you did `InfoBuckets[index] = new InitialInfo();` in the `InitialInsert` method?

Comment: Remove the array of pointers, and you have a chance of a +1. Otherwise, at least make is smart pointers :-(

Comment: Took David Isla's advice and got it working. (I knew it was a stupid problem, but thanks for indulging me. :) )

Comment: @SamIam you can do it, but I think that this program is only a sketch. Would you use an index variable in an Initializer function? Only Kalie knows it ;)